# a question about poles of meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Justify true or false** : If $f$ is meromorphic and has an infinite number of poles, then every closed disk $|z|\leq R$ $(0<R<\infty)$
> contains only a finite number of poles inside it.

Considering $f(z)=\tan z$ , we can see that its poles are $\displaystyle z=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$ , which are contained finitely in some of the closed disks . I wonder if there is a counterexample by which we can show that it is not true for all meromorphic functions as such. Am I on the right track, or is this statement indeed true? Any help is appreciated.

**N.B. -** There is also a statement I remember that if $f$ has an infinite number of poles inside a simple closed contour $C$, then some subsequence of them would converge to non-isolated singularity of $f$. But I'm not  quite sure whether that would help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Meromorphic functions are defined to those which have possible singularities at pole only. Now, if there are infinite number of poles, say, $(z_n)$inside a closed disk, Heine-Borel will tell you that there must be a limit point inside that disk of the poles, say, $z_0$. But then this $z_0$ is a non-isolated singularity, contrary to the definition of meromorphic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Meromorphic functions are analytic except for isolated singularities (which are poles). Isolated singularities form a set with no limit points. Since closed disks are compact there can only be finite number of isolated singularities  inside them.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is meromorphic, then $f=\frac gh$, where $g$ and $h$ ara anlytic functions, and $h$ is not the null function. Every pole of $f$ is a zero of $h$. And a closed disk is compact, and therefore it can only contain finitely many zeros of $h$; otherwise, it would follow from the identity theorem that $h$ is the null function, because then the set of zeros of $h$ would have an accumulation point.